# Multiple assignments under 'if' statement

Tags: python

Why can't I make multiple assignments under an if statement in python?  Is there some syntax I am missing?

I want to do this:

```
files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

print "\nThe following files are available: \n"

i = 0
for file in files:
    i = i + 1
    print i, file

choice = int(raw_input("\Enter a file number: "))

if choice ==1:
    file = np.genfromtxt(files[0], usecols = (1,2,3), dtype = (float), delimiter = '\t')
    time = np.genfromtxt(files[0], usecols = (0), dtype = (str), delimiter = '\t')

print time
```

Time is defined outside of my if statement, so it doesn't change as choice changes...what the heck?

Comment: `time` is a poor variable name in Python since it shadows the `time` module...

Comment: What are your input and output?

Comment: well actually that is to provide means of an example, but thanks for the reminder.

Comment: `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple while `(0)` is not (nor `(float)`, nor `(str)`). This could cause the error. It's difficult to say more than this if you don't paste the error message.

Comment: You *can* make multiple assignments under the `if`. Your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Definitely i think the error is caused by wrong parameters. I never used numpy but standing from [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt): "usecols : sequence or None". Use `(0,)` instead of `(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variables file and time must be defined at an higher block level than your if statement.

Be careful with "time", as it is the name of a python module. You should use a variation of this name (time_ for example).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any other choice except for `1` and it will give error if choice is not `1`, you code should be something like this

```
choice = int(raw_input("\Enter a file number: "))
choice -= 1 # array index is from 0

if choice < 0 or > 2:
    print "Enter correct choice"
    sys.exit()

file = np.genfromtxt(files[choice], usecols = (1,2,3), dtype = (float), delimiter = '\t')
time = np.genfromtxt(files[choice], usecols = (0), dtype = (str), delimiter = '\t')
```

Comment: ok, that was only one section of the code...I just wanted to know why I cannot assign more than one variable under the if statement...